# Trouble with uniqueness of Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So, theory of partial differential equations tell us that there is always a unique solution to every Cauchy problem. So, a problem to find $u \in C^1(D) \bigcap C(\overline{D})$, where $C^1$ means continuously differentiable function, such that $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+\sin(x)$ and $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$ is a Cauchy problem and has unique solution. Observe functions $u=\sin(x)$ and $u_1= \frac{t^2}{2}\sin(x)+\sin(x)\cos(t)$. Now, if I am not completely retarded, those two are BOTH solutions. But that is impossible, because of theory forbids that. Can anybody tell me what is going on here? Thanks a lot.

Please feel free to tell me that I am retarded or that I shall go to kindergarten because even kids would see the answer.

P.S. Wolfram alpha does not solve partial differential equations (simply, notation $u_{tt}$ drives wolfram alpha crazy). Any suggestions on some free-to-download or online partial differential equation "solutioner"?

Comment: Actually, $u_1$ is not a solution. $u_{1,tt} = \sin(x) - \sin(x)\cos(t)$ and $u_{1,xx} = -t^2\sin(x)/2 - \sin(x)\cos(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I am a blind and completely absolutely retarded and my IQ is strictly less than zero, and my brain does not have a mass(its mass is 0 grams)

Anyone with IQ bigger or equal to zero will ask what is $D$. Here , $D$ is a $R \times (0,+\infty)$, what is unbounded. Now, with a  higher amount than 0 grams of brain one surely knows that there is an additional condition for unbounded regions for unique solution: bounded solution!!!!

Thanks anyway.